# Loading components dynamically in angular 2+

Tags: angular, dynamic

I want component X to be able to contain component Y or component Z,

in order to do this I tried using the following angular example:
https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

but this example, just loads it as a view, so the module of the component is not loaded and all of its functionality cannot be used.

do I need to load the module separately? what should I be doing differently?

Comment: Have a look at this [**medium post**](https://medium.com/@aravindfz/load-modal-component-dynamically-in-angular-5fda8e1dc3e7)

Comment: haven't seen any difference in this post from the documentation I used